# Is it correct to use the word ‘transit’?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Is it okay to use the word  *transit* as it is in the following structure:

> to enable **the transit of the road**...

to make the road possible to go across it?

Comment: When you say "*make the road possible to go across it*", are you referring to the lie of the road (e.g. East/West), or fact that people can cross its width? In your quoted sentence fragment, *transit* looks like it relates more to the former, but it could refer to the *people* given an appropriate context.

Comment: *...to enable [**traversal**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/traversal?s=t) of the road.* I wouldn't normally include an article *(**the** traversal)*, but that's a stylistic choice. Note that the object of ***transit*** is usually ***something which is moved** [from one place to another]*, as in *the transit of goods by rail*.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things wrong with your phrase. First, the dictionary says the word [transit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/transit) is uncountable. Second, and less important, *of* is the wrong preposition here.  So you want to say

> enable transit on the road,

or

> enable transit along the road,

or maybe (if you're talking about going from one side of the road to the other)

> enable transit across the road.

(Actually, *transit* is countable for some senses: a single instance of transit – the act of passing across something – would be countable. So if you're talking about making it possible for one specific group of people to go down the road, you could use *the transit*.)

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to use "transit" in the sense of "navigable".

The Oxford English Dictionaries (on-line) define *navigable* as applicable to both waterways and roads:

> navigable adjective
>
> ```
> 1(of a waterway or sea) able to be sailed on by ships or boats.
> ‘a navigable channel’
> ‘many of the rivers ceased to be navigable’
> ```
>
> Synonyms: **passable, negotiable, traversable, able to be sailed on,
>   able to be travelled on, crossable**
>
> ```
> 1.1 **(of a track or road) suitable for vehicles.**
> ‘a good cart track, navigable by cars’
> ```
>
> 1.2 Computing (of a website) easy to move around in.

When roads or highways in the U.S. are closed by mud slides or accidents, we talk about when they will be *reopened*; I'd express your phase as "**enable travel on the road**."

Comment: Is it better to use ‘travel’ instead of ‘transit’?? The sentence: “Please do not park directly in front of the houses to enable travel on the road and your undisturbed stay.